# Magento 2 vault stored cards deleted in frontend but still displaying in admin

Tags: magento2, store-credit

Magento 2 vault stored cards deleted in frontend but still displaying in admin.

Enabled Brain tree store cards options in admin, 
From frontend when placing order check to save cards options and place the order like this I added two cards and deleted one card from the frontend.
But in admin placing the order for the customer, it's displaying two cards.

In `vault_payment_token` table `is_active` is 1, `is_visible` is 0 and `customer_id` is 237887.
**What scenario it is stored like this** I didn't understand there are hundreds of records.

**Frontend stored cards**
[image: Frontend stored cards]

================================================================================

**Admin place order**
[image: Admin place order]

================================================================================

**Database records**
[image: Database records]

**For Customer Orders 11**

in `vault_payment_token` table `is_active` is 1, `is_visible` is 1 and `customer_id` is 237887.

**For Guest Orders 10**

in `vault_payment_token` table `is_active` is 1, `is_visible` is 0 and `customer_id` is NULL.

**No Values saved like this 00**